# Is there any way to extract audio from video url without saving the video locally?

Tags: python, url, audio, video

I have some video urls, i want to use python to extract their audio as wav file directly without saving videos on my locally disk, for there are too many videos.

Many ways i have found are firstly save video on disk, and then use ffmpeg to convert to audio.

Comment: `and then use ffmpeg to convert to audio` why not specify the input of ffmpeg to be the remote address, and stream it into the converter instead?

Answer (score 0):

*"Many ways i have found are firstly save video on disk, and then use ffmpeg to convert to audio."*

Use the web URL as input (so input is not a file on disk, but is file-path on HTTP server).

```
ffmpeg -i http://www.website.com/file.mp4 -c:a copy audiofile.m4a
```